# Deleting a table in Oracle with WHERE condition in other tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, A and B, in Oracle:

```
   A (a1, a2)

   B (b1, b2, b3, b4, b5)
```

And some rows like:

```
  A(type1, 192.168.94.1)
   A(type1, 192.168.94.2)
   A(type2, 192.168.94.1)

   B(type1, 192, 168, 94, 1)
   B(type1, 192, 168, 94, 3)
   B(type2, 192, 168, 94, 2)
```

In table A, we have **A(type1, 192.168.94.1)**

In table B, we also have **B(type1, 192, 168, 94, 1)**

In table A, I want delete the row

```
   A(type1, 192.168.94.1)
```

Because its type like the type in table B

```
   A.a1 = B.b1
   -> type1 = type1
```

and the ip address duplicate when concatenating in B

```
   A.a2 = B.b2 ||'.'|| B.b3 ||'.'|| B.b4 ||'.'|| B.5
   -> 192.168.94.1 = 192.168.94.1
```

Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Try the code I gave you after you edited your question and explained better what you wanted to achieve. Also don't just say "doesn't work" provide error messages or a reason why it hasn't achieved what you wanted.

Comment: To be honest I'd just drop table `a` or table `b`. You don't need them both as they seem to hold the same data.

Comment: @Ben: It is a defect fixing so I cannot drop table a. I want delete some obsolete rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delete from A
where ROWID in 
    (select A.ROWID
     from A,B
     where A.A1 = B.B1
     and A.A2 = concat(B.B2, B.B3, B.B4)
    )
```

Comment: good use of ROWID but I'd be inclined to use the SQL-92 syntax rather than the older SQL-86 for the join condition - YMMV.

Comment: This solution is also better than WHERE EXISTS, because this solution is using indices. I've compared the explain plan for WHERE EXISTS and this ROWID solution. In the WHERE EXISTS case a full table scan was done.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us much information about what exactly you are trying to do but I assume you wish to delete rows from `A` where there is a link to `B`, you could try:

```
DELETE FROM a
 WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
         FROM B
        WHERE a.a1 = b.b1
          AND a.a2 = CONCAT(b.b2, b.b3, b.b4));
```

Assumptions:

1) The links between table `A` and `B` are correct in your original post
2) You are only wanting to delete the records from table `A`

Hope it helps...

**EDIT:** 
After your new comments the question is murkier still. 
I do not know whether you want to delete just the IP column data or the duplicate rows from table `A`.

If you want to just delete the duplicate rows from table `A` then it is simple:

```
DELETE FROM A
 WHERE rowid NOT IN
            (SELECT MIN(rowid)
               FROM A
              GROUP BY a1, a2);
```

**This assumes that columns a1 and a2 are your primary key for table `A`.**

Could you also indicate why you think you need to link to table `B` at all?

Comment: Hi Ollie, your sql statement delete entire rows. i have just added some examples above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be fair your question indicated that you wanted to delete the entire row. After the edits, it still does. Are you saying you want to delete only the duplicate rows in table `A` where there is a link to table `B`?

Comment: Yes, I want delete only. I have just edit the script in my code as you advised, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: From what you are saying the link to table `B` is not needed. I have edited my answer to help you remove all duplicate rows from table `A`. Also "Doesn't work" is not helpful. Post an error message or tell me why it "doesn't work".

Comment: I will try your code soon. I have got some problems with my Oracle server so I cannot test your code. Hope this run ;)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am very sorry about my cloudy question that make a misunderstand.

Comment: No problem, though it would be nice if you could upvote the answers that were helpful to you as a reward for the effort the posters took to respond.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're not finding anything to delete because you may not be joining the two tables correctly, because your concat will give you `concat('192', '168', '94', '1') = '192168941'`, which is different to `'192.168.94.1'`

```
delete from A a
 where exists (
   select 1
     from B b
    where a.a1 = b.b1
      and a.a2 = b.b2 || '.' || b.b3 || '.' || b.b4 || '.' || b.b5)
```

EDIT:

Using `concat` for concatenating nine parameters resulted in a `too many parameters` exception, so I'm using the `||` operator instead.

Comment: @beny23, See my answer and the comment trail. I don't think the OP actually wants to link from table `A` to `B` at all. It's all a bit cloudy what is actually being asked.

Answer (score 0):

I come from the SQL Server world, so I tried this:

```
delete 
from E_CRM_ACTIVITYPOINTER ap
   inner join tmp_activitypointer_for_delete d
       on AP.ACTIVITYID = d.activityid
where ap.current_flag = 1
    and d.start_date != AP.START_DATE
```

That didn't work in my Oracle 11g enviroment, so I modified to this:

```
delete 
from E_CRM_ACTIVITYPOINTER
where (ACTIVITYID,START_DATE) in 
    (
    select AP.ACTIVITYID, AP.START_DATE
    from E_CRM_ACTIVITYPOINTER ap
        inner join tmp_activitypointer_for_delete d
        on AP.ACTIVITYID = d.activityid
    where ap.current_flag = 1
        and d.start_date != AP.START_DATE
    )
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.